# Making noise animation loop smoothly

Tags: animation

I made a camera shake with a noise modifier but it doesn't loop very well. I would upload a video but I can't so I'll try to give as much information as I can.

Graph editor:
[image]

Noise Modifier:

[image]

Would anybody know how I could smoothly loop a noise modifier animation?

Comment: if it's only 150 frame long you could keyframe it manually instead of using a Noise modifier?